# Segmentation Fault in C in my code in linux

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference

I'm just learning pointers in C now, and Im confused as to how they would work in my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>


    #define MAX_ARR  64
    #define MAX_STR  32

    typedef enum { COMEDY, DRAMA, HORROR, SCIFI 
    } GenreType;

    typedef struct {
      char title[MAX_STR];
      char director[MAX_STR];
      int  year;
      GenreType genre;
    } MovieType;

    void initMovie(char*, char*, int*, GenreType, MovieType*);
    void printMovies(MovieType*, int);
    void readString(char*);
    void readInt(int*);


    int main()
    {
       MovieType movie;
       MovieType movieArr[MAX_ARR];
       MovieType *pMovie;
       char t = movie.title;
       int arrSize = 0;

       printf("Please enter the tile of the movie: ");
       readString(t);
       printf("The title of the movie is: %c\n", (t));

       return 0;
    }

void initMovie(char *t, char *d, int *y, GenreType gentype, MovieType *movType)
{

}

void readString(char *str)
{
  char tmpStr[MAX_STR];

  fgets(tmpStr, sizeof(tmpStr), stdin);
  tmpStr[strlen(tmpStr)-1] = '\0';
  strcpy(str, tmpStr);
}

void readInt(int *x)
{
  char str[MAX_STR];

  readString(str);
  sscanf(str, "%d", x);
}
```

I'm trying to ask the user to fill in all the data of the movie types such as `title`, `director`, `year` it came out etc. As you can see, my current method produces a `segmentation fault`, so clearly I'm doing something wrong. Everything outside of the `main` function cannot be altered, except for the `initMovie` function and the `printMovies` function (not yet made).

Any tips and pointers, pun intended, would be greatly appreciated! Let me know what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it!

Comment: The statement `tmpStr[strlen(tmpStr)-1] = '\0'` does not make sense, `strlen` calculates the length of the string by searching for the 0, and then you place a 0 where there already was one. Maybe you meant  `tmpStr[MAX_STR-1] = '\0'`?

Comment: That was not made by me, but the prof. I can't alter it either way

Comment: @KarstenKoop Actually it's stripping the trailing `\n` which fgets() will store. So it does make sense, ugly as it is.

Comment: You are right, `tmpStr[strlen(tmpStr)-1]` is the last character of the string, not the terminating 0. Off-by-one error by me

Comment: Please do not vandalize your own posts.

Comment: `char t = movie.title;` is an error. Your compiler should say something about this. It's important to fix all messages reported by the compiler before running your program.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `char t = movie.title;` into `readString(t);`. It's incorrect. `readString` expects a pointer `char*`.

Comment: +1, and the format string will then need to be `%s` not `%c`, and the varargs arguments don't need to be in brackets like Python.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.
So basically there was two different issues.

1. Like the first guy said you were using `char t = movie.title;` when you should of been using `char* t = movie.title;`
2. In: `printf("The title of the movie is: %c\n", (t));` you should have been using `%s` not `%c`. So like this: `printf("The title of the movie is: %s\n", (t));`

Good luck on your assignment. I compiled using Mac OS X but it should work on linux.